# CSS max width, responsive design

Tags: css

I'm working on my friends website to make it mobile friendly. He doesn't want a new site just to limit certain elements of the site for mobile users. So, I added a media query in CSS.

Here is the problem so far: When I view this site on my phone the content is not fitting to the viewport and I have to scroll (left to right) to view full site.. I'm not sure how to manipulate "max-width" properties correctly to make everything fit properly on mobile.

Here is a link to the code pen where I've started my draft:
http://codepen.io/twesh/pen/RpwxLR?editors=1100

I'd be glad to clarify anything, all help is appreciated.

Thanks, 
Twesh

```css
body {
 background:black;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

html{
  margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

a {
 color: #FFFF00;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
        }

h1 img {
 display: block;
}

img {
 border: 0;
 overflow-x:scroll;
}

h1 {
  color: #FDE7C2;
  background: #991111;
  border: 2px solid #C4B888;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 25px "Times new roman", sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0 2px 21px;
}


#wrap {
 background:#25383C;
 float: center;
 margin: auto;
}

#topbar {
 width: 99%;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 float: center;
 font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}

#header {
 height: auto;
 width: 99%;
 background: #800517;
 float: center;
}


/**************** menu coding *****************/


#menu {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 12em;
background:#800517;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
float: center;
}


#menu ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 7.5em;
float: left;
}


#menu a, #menu h2 {
font: bold 10px/16px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
display: block;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
margin: 0;
padding: 2px 3px;
float: center;
text-align: center;
}

#menu h2 {
color: #260403;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu a {
color: #FFF;
white-space:nowrap;
background-image:url(/assets/nav.gif);
text-decoration: none;
float: center;
}

#menu a:hover {
color: #a00;
background: #fff;
float: center;
}

#menu li {position: relative;}

#menu ul ul {
position: absolute;
z-index: 500;
}

#menu ul ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 100%;
}

div#menu ul ul,
div#menu ul li:hover ul ul,
div#menu ul ul li:hover ul ul
{display: none;}

div#menu ul li:hover ul,
div#menu ul ul li:hover ul,
div#menu ul ul ul li:hover ul
{display: block;}


<!--[if IE]>

 #menu ul li {float: center; width: 100%;}

<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>

body {
background: repeat-y;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
font-size: 100%;
float: center;
}

#menu ul li a {height: 1%;} 

#menu a, #menu h2 {
font: bold italic 1.1em/1.2em Times New Roman, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

<![endif]-->

#topbar {
 width: 99%;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 float: center;
 font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}


#homebody {
 height: auto;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 color:#151B54;
 float: center;
}

h2 {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
 font:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:20px;
 font-style:italic;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
h2 b{
 color:#FFFF00;
}



.textl{
font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#FFFFFF;
line-height:18px;
padding-right:15px;
font-weight:normal;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:left;
}

.textr{
font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#FFFFFF;
line-height:18px;
padding-right:15px;
font-weight:normal;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:right;
}

.textc{
font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#FFFFFF;
line-height:18px;
padding-right:15px;
font-weight:normal;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
}

.textj{
font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#FFFFFF;
line-height:18px;
padding-right:15px;
font-weight:normal;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:justify;
}

#botline {
 height: 16px;
 width: 99%;
 margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
 float: center;
}

#footer {
 clear:both;
 text-align:center;
 float: center;
}

#copyright {
 clear:both;
 margin:0 auto;
 float: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1099px) {
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Open+Sans+Condensed:300');

  html{
    background-color:white;
   padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
  td{
    max-width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  }
  
  body{
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    float:left;
    max-width:100%;
    color:black;
    
  }

  #topbar{
    display:none;
  }
  
  #menu{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
        position:fixed;
    
  }
  
  #menu ul:nth-child(1) {
  margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
    #menu ul:nth-child(5) {
  margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    position:relative;
      left:8em;
      top:-4.4em;
  }
  
  #menu ul:nth-child(7) {
  margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
        position:relative;
      left:16em;
      top:-8.5em;
  }
  
  #menu ul:nth-child(2){
    display:none;
  }
  
    #menu ul:nth-child(3){
    display:none;
  }
  
    #menu ul:nth-child(4){
    display:none;
  }
  
    #menu ul:nth-child(6){
    display:none;
  }
  

  
#homebody  .textj td[width="40%"] {
  display: none;
}
  
  #kaliPujainCT{
      margin: auto auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: ;
  padding: 0px;
  color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <meta name="keywords" content="bengali, bangla, naska, NASKA, kalipuja, connecticut, india, kali puja, kali puja in connecticut" />
 <meta name="description" content="Kali puja in connecticut" />

 <title>Welcome to NASKA</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/style_1024.css" type="text/css" />


        <script type="text/javascript">
          if (screen.width > 1024)
            link = document.getElementsByTagName( "link" )[ 0 ];
            link.href = "/includes/style_1268.css";


                function expandCollapse() 
                {   
                    for (var i=0; i<expandCollapse.arguments.length; i++) 
                    {   
                        var element = document.getElementById(expandCollapse.arguments[i]);   
                        element.style.display = (element.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";   
                    }   
                }  
        </script> 


 <script language="JavaScript1.1">
 var slideimages=new Array()
 function slideshowimages(){
 for (i=0;i<slideshowimages.arguments.length;i++){
 slideimages[i]=new Image()
 slideimages[i].src=slideshowimages.arguments[i]
 }
 }

 </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var fb_param = {};
fb_param.pixel_id = '6012379506235';
fb_param.value = '0.00';
fb_param.currency = 'USD';
(function(){
  var fpw = document.createElement('script');
  fpw.async = true;
  fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
  var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
})();
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=6012379506235&amp;value=0&amp;currency=USD" />
</noscript>


</head>
<body>



       <div id="topbar" class="textc"> 
                <img height=65px src="/assets/banner.jpg" width="100%" >
   <strong>A non-profit 501(c)(3) Tax Exempt Organization incorporated in the state of Connecticut</strong>


  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,150,150" href="/admin.php">
       </div>


       <div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/index.php">Home<br>&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>


<ul>
  <li><a href="#">About<br>Us<img src="/assets/menudown.png"></a>
    <ul>
           <li><a href="/about.php">About<br>Us</a>
           <li><a href="/sponsors.php">Sponsors<img src="/assets/menudown.png"></a>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="/spnsr2016.php">2016</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/spnsr2015.php">2015</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/spnsr2014.php">2014</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/spnsr2013.php">2013</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/spnsr2012.php">2012</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/spnsr2011.php">2011</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/spnsr2010.php">2010</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Feedback<br>&nbsp;<img src="/assets/menudown.png"></a>
    <ul>
         <li><a href="/fb2010.php">Send Feedback</a></li>
         <li><a href="/fbview.php">View Feedback</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>



<ul>
  <li><a href="#">News<br>Highlights<img src="/assets/menudown.png"></a>
    <ul>
           <li><a href="/news.php">Newsflash</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Highlights<img src="/assets/menudown.png"></a>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="/hlt2016.php">2016</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/hlt2015.php">2015</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/hlt2014.php">2014</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/hlt2013.php">2013</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/hlt2012.php">2012</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/hlt2011.php">2011</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/hlt2010.php">2010</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery<br>&nbsp;<img src="/assets/menudown.png"></a>
    <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Programs<img src="/assets/menudown.png"></a>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="/glry2015.php">2015</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/glry2014.php">2014</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/glry2013.php">2013</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">2012<img src="/assets/menudown.png"></a>
                       <ul>
                     <li><a href="/glry2012.php">Kalipuja</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/glryqz2012.php">NASKA Quiz</a></li>
                 </ul>
                   </li>

                   <li><a href="/glry2011.php">2011</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/glry2010.php">2010</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Dignitaries'<br>Messages<img src="/assets/menudown.png"></a>
    <ul>

           <li><a href="#">2015<img src="/assets/menudown.png"></a>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="/wh2015.php">White House</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/cgny2015.php">Consul General<br>of India</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/govct2015.php">Governor of CT</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>


           <li><a href="#">2014<img src="/assets/menudown.png"></a>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="/cgny2014.php">Consul General<br>of India</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/govct2014.php">Governor of CT</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>


           <li><a href="#">2013<img src="/assets/menudown.png"></a>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="/cgny2013.php">Consul General<br>of India</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/govct2013.php">Governor of CT</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>

           <li><a href="#">2012<img src="/assets/menudown.png"></a>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="/cgny2012.php">Consul General<br>of India</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/govct2012.php">Governor of CT</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>

           <li><a href="#">2011<img src="/assets/menudown.png"></a>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="/cgny2011.php">Consul General<br>of India</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/govct2011.php">Governor of CT</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>



<ul>
    <li><a href="/contact.php">Contact<br>Us</a></li>
</ul>
       </div>

 <br><br><br>
       <div id="topbar"> 
       <marquee behavior=alternate>
<strong>

<br>

</strong>
</marquee>



       </div>

       <div id="homebody">




           <p class="textc">

   <font size="4" color="#52F3FF">
   
   <br>
   </font>
           </p>

           <p class="textj">


             <table class="textj" border="0"  align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 


             <tr> 

               <td align="center" valign="center" colspan=4>

               </td>
             </tr>

             <tr> 

               <td>
              </td>

              <td id="kaliPujainCT" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor=#003300>
   <p class="textc">
   <font size="4" color="#FFA500">
   <strong>Kalipuja in Connecticut</strong>
   </font> 
   </p>
  </td> 

  <td> 
   <p class="textc">

   </p>
  </td> 

              <td id="event" valign="top" align="center" width="40%" bgcolor=#003300>
   <p class="textc">
   <font size="4" color="#FFA500">
   <strong>Event</strong>
   </p>
  </td>

             </tr> 

             <tr> 

               <td align="center" valign="top" width="10%" rowspan=3>
   <br>
               

              </td>

              <td align="center" valign="top">
   <br>
   <img width = 500 src="/assets/maa/01.jpg" name="slide" border=0></a>
   <script>
   
   slideshowimages("/assets/maa/01.jpg"
                  ,"/assets/maa/02.jpg"
                  ,"/assets/maa/03.jpg"
                  ,"/assets/maa/04.jpg"
                  ,"/assets/maa/05.jpg"
      )

   var slideshowspeed=3500

   var whichimage=0
   function slideit(){
   if (!document.images)
    return
    document.images.slide.src=slideimages[whichimage].src
   if (whichimage<slideimages.length-1)
    whichimage++
   else
    whichimage=0
    setTimeout("slideit()",slideshowspeed)
   }
   slideit()


   </script>


   </font> 

   <br>


   We'd be delighted to hear back from you. Please share your views/opinions using the link below.
   <br>
   <a href="/fb2010.php"><img src="/assets/Feedback_Off.png" onmouseover="this.src='/assets/Feedback_On.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/assets/Feedback_Off.png'; "/></a>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>

   <font size="5" color="#FF4600">
    <strong>Feedback Received</strong>
   </font>

   <p class="textl">

              
   <img src="/assets/maa/jb.png">Mahua and I thoroughly enjoyed Kali Puja festivities 2014. It was clear to us that every detail was addressed with tender loving care so that such a huge undertaking could run so seamlessly. It did not happen by chance! It was a big task and NASKA organizers came through wonderfully. The food was great and plentiful. 
<br><br>
The souvenir magazine looks and reads just great ... fantastic layout ... fantastic literary and artistic pieces. My special thanks to Animesh for editing the souvenir again this year.  He always does a super job of editing. I remain grateful.
<br><br>
The musical program was delightful  ... Mahua and I especially liked Kinjal's performance ... so young and yet Kinjal could carry the big audience. He has a great future ahead as long as he stays humble. 
<br><br>
In the end, let me congratulate all office-bearers of NASKA for their selfless dedication and love. In everything NASKA does, that genuine dedication and love show!
   <br>
              
   </p>
   <p class="textr">
    <a href="/fbview.php">More >></a>
   </p>


                <a href="https://www.yelp.com/biz/amba-vilas-palace-danbury/" target=_blank><img align="left" width="300" src="/assets/amba.gif"></a>
                <a href="http://www.zaroka.com/" target=_blank><img align="right" width="300" src="/assets/zaroka_adh.gif"></a>
   </p>
  </td> 
  <td> 
  </td> 
              <td id="event2" valign="top" align="center" width="40%">
  
   <br>
   
   <font size="10" color="#FFA500">
   <a href="/hlt2016.php"><strong>Kalipuja 2016</strong></a>
   </font>
   <br><br>
   Please click on the above link for more details
   <br><br>

   Thank you all for attending Kalipuja 2016 
   <br><br>
   Hope to see you in 2017 Kalipuja
   <br>



  </td>

             </tr> 

             <tr> 

              <td bgcolor=#003300>
   <p class="textc">
   <font size="4" color="#FFA500">
   <strong>Welcome</strong>
   </font> 
   </p>
  </td> 
  <td> 
   <p class="textc">

   </p>
  </td> 
              <td id="newsAndEvents" valign="top" align="center" width="40%" bgcolor=#003300>
   <p class="textc">
   <font size="4" color="#FFA500">
   <strong>News and Events </strong>
   </p>
  </td>

             </tr> 

              <td valign="top" align="center" width="50%">
   <p class="textl">
   NASKA, a charitable, tax-exempt, 501(c)(3) organization, is dedicated to promote cultural diversity, 
   to participate in educational activity and to contribute to humanitarian cause. 
   <br>
   We are committed to sharing South Asian heritage with everyone in North America. 
   <br>
   We embrace diversity and inclusion by inviting people from all walks of life to our social events. 
   <br><br>
   </p>

   <img align="left" src="/assets/maa/pradeep.jpg"><img align="right" src="/assets/maa/offer.jpg">
   <br><br>
                <a href="http://www.crsgh.com/" target=_blank><img align="center" width="200" src="/assets/crs.jpg"></a>

   
  </td>
  <td> 
   <p class="textc">

   </p>
  </td> 
              <td id="newsAndEvents2" valign="top" align="center" width="40%">
   <p class="textl">
              
   <img src="/assets/maa/jb.png">NASKA General Body meeting on 06/25/2016 <br><a href="/assets/docs/MOM_2016_06_25.pdf" target="_blank">(Download Minutes)</a>   <br>
              
   <img src="/assets/maa/jb.png">NASKA General Body meeting on 02/27/2016 <br><a href="/assets/docs/MOM_2016_02_27.pdf" target="_blank">(Download Minutes)</a>   <br>
              
   <img src="/assets/maa/jb.png">More than 550 devotees attended Kalipuja 2015.
   <br>
              
   <img src="/assets/maa/jb.png">Debojit Saha will rock the NASKA audience this year (2015).   <br>
              
   <img src="/assets/maa/jb.png">NASKA General Body meeting on 03/14/2015 <br><a href="/assets/docs/MoM_2015_03_14.pdf" target="_blank">(Download Minutes)</a>   <br>
              
   </p>
   <p class="textr">
    <a href="/news.php">More >></a>
   </p>
  </td>


             </tr> 

             </table> 

    

  </p>
       </div>




       <div id="footer">   
         <table align="left" width=100% border="0">
            <tr>
              <td colspan=3 align="center">
   &nbsp;
  </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
               <td align="left">
                   <a 

href="http://www.facebook.com//n/?group.php&amp;gid=389071392384&amp;mid=ebaa21e19aabde2f7a3fa23a140

8ea0f" target="_blank">
                   <img width="30" height="30" src="/assets/facebook.png" alt="Join us on 

Facebook"/>
                   </a>
                   <a href="http://www.twitter.com/naskact" target="_blank">
                   <img  width="30" height="30" 

src="http://twitter-badges.s3.amazonaws.com/t_logo-a.png" alt="Follow NASKA on Twitter"/>
                   </a>
                   <a href="http://www.orkut.com/Main#Community?rl=cpp&cmm=99586925" 

target="_blank">
                   <img  width="30" height="30" src="/assets/orkut.png" alt="Join our Community in 

Orkut"/>
                   </a>
               </td>

               <td align="center">
               &nbsp;

               </td>

               <td align="right">



               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>

       </div>




  <div id="copyright">
         <p class="textc"><strong>&copy; 2010 www.naska.org. All right reserved. 
   <br>123481 visits so far</strong></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how `max-width` works in different contexts.  There are two different places that you might see `max-width`:

**1: As a CSS property in a CSS rule-set**

```
.menubar {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 980px;
}
```

The above rule states that, for any element with the class of `menubar`, you would like it to take up 100% of the width of the containing element *but only up to 980px*, after which point it will remain that width.

**2: As part of a media query**

```
.menubar {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 980px;
    color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .menubar {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

In this context the `@media screen and (max-width: 360px) { ... }` states that any rules between the squiggly brackets will only be true for the [media type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) of a `screen` device and when the viewport is `360px`.  So, for any viewport width of `360px` or less the color of the font in an element with class of `.menubar` will override the color set above and become `red` -- when the viewport width gets above `360px`, the media query will cease being applicable and the color will go back to `black` as set in the first rule.

If there is already CSS written for the full-width/desktop size of your friend's site, I would recommend simply adding onto that style sheet with mobile-specific rules by creating a mobile-specific media query. Something like:

```
@media (min-width:320px)  {
    /*All rules in here will only apply to screens 320px wide or shorter*/
    /*(Although you still have to consider CSS specificity*/
}
```

Keep in mind you'll still need to consider [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

You may also need to acquaint yourself with the [Viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) as part of the endeavor.

Finally, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile) enumerating the best media query breakpoints may be helpful.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), that may help you in creating a responsive design. Having horizontal scrollbars may mean that one or more elements are out of the body's boundaries. You may also try using the Developer's Tool (F12 in Chrome) to check for errors and such